How do AC and DC work in this amplifier circuit?
I have questions about this nice example circuit, found here:
Help understanding AC signal across a charged (coupling) capacitor

What is the voltage between across V_RC and C_Out at DC, +1V and -1V peak?
Why is the voltage across C_In 2.6 VDC?
Does the voltage at the base changes in time?



Please include more detail as to what you mean about the voltage "between across V_RC and C_Out". Do you mean simply the voltage appearing on the collector of the transistor?

Yes, I mean the voltage at the collector. Sorry, it was missleading.

I have posted a lengthy answer. If you read it carefully, step-by-step, you should be able to uderstand.

Thank you Edin!

Maybe one more question about the coupling and decoupling capacitors C_In and C_out. How do they work in detail?

Capacitors simply serve to separate DC components of the signal, so the DC voltage on either end will not be passed on, while the AC voltage passes through, ideally without being reduced. For most intents and purposes, you can assume that the capacitor "ignores" DC voltages and reflects only the AC voltages. As you probably know, a capacitor acts as a short circuit when empty and a voltage is applied across it, and then acts like an insulator if the applied voltage stays the same. If the voltage changes, it charges or discharges the capacitor until the two voltages are equal.

@EdinFifić Hi, I know. If I have more questions, I will come back to you, but for now it's clear. Thank you!

@EdinFifić One more question. The voltage at the base is changing between the half-cycles?

Yes, as you can see from your own posted image and from my explanation. The voltage (potential) at the base changes with the input signal, and the potential at the emitter follows it (minus 0.6V base-emitter voltage drop). That's the beauty of quickly checking a bipolar transistor if it is biased or it works properly; its base-emitter voltage should be approximately the specified base-emitter forward voltage drop in the vast majority of cases, and it is mostly around 0.6-0.7V.

Thank you. That explains everything.

Just a minor correction: 0.6V between base and emitter does not automatically mean that the transistor is not faulty or that the circuit functions properly. It could simply mean that the base-emitter junction is OK and forward biased while the collector-base or collector-emitter junction is faulty (open or short).

I know, what you mean

I will answer your second question first, because it will help you understand the answer to your first question.
Why is the voltage across Cin 2.6V?

To understand this, it would help to study this type of an amplifier circuit, but I will summarize it here.
The DC operating point (the point when there is no input signal) of a transistor amplifier is typically set to result in about half of the supply voltage on the collector (as you can see it is 6V here), so that the output voltage can swing equally in both positive AND negative directions, resulting in a maximum output voltage swing or amplitude.
The collector resistor is chosen to fit in the middle of the transistor's "load line" (I will not go further into this here).
Since we have 6V across the 10kΩ Rc here, its current is 6V/10kΩ=0.6mA.
Since the beta (β), or the amplification (ratio of collector current to base current) here is 99, that means the DC base current is Ic/β or 0.6mA/99=0.00606mA or about 6.0606μA.
NOW we get to the point how is the base potential 2.6V here!
Since the emitter current equals the sum of the base and collector currents, it will be 0.60606mA total.
Multiplying the emitter current with the emitter resistor value of 3.3kΩ, we get about 2V (0.60606mA x 3.3kΩ = 1.99998V).
Since the typical base-emitter voltage drop is assumed to be around 0.6V, that's how we get the 2.6V on the base.
The base-biasing resistor RB is calculated to provide about 6.06μA to the base when the base potential is 2.6V and its supply voltage is 5V, which is 5V-2.6V=2.4V, so 2.4V/6.0606μA equals about 400kΩ.
And THAT'S how we get the 2.6V on the base.
NOW we can go on to understand how to calculate the Rc voltages during the positive and negative voltage swings on the input.

The input voltage swing of +1V gets superimposed (added) onto the existing 2.6V, resulting in 3.6V.
Taking away the base-emitter voltage drop of 0.6V we get 3V on across the emitter resistor.
This results in the emitter current of 900μA, which is composed of base current (1%) and collector current (99%, as β is 99).
The collector current is then 0.99x900μA=891μA or 0.891mA.
Multiplying this new collector current with the collector resistor (Rc) value we get 0.891mAx10kΩ=8.91V.
This resistor voltage is subtracted from the +12Vdc supply to get the collector potential of 12-8.91=3.09 volts.
This means that the output voltage is inverted and amplified about 3 times, which can also be calculated from the ratio of the Rc to Re, since almost the same current flows through both.
The opposite happens with a negative 1V on the input.
To make calculations easier, assume that the Rc and Re currents are approximately equal.
I will let you do the simple math yourself here:


Awesome explanation. Thank you so much!

@TRAXX If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted (there is a checkmark under the upvote and downvote buttons), so that the system shows your question as answered. You can also upvote my answer at the same time if it was helpful. That lets others know it was a good answer. Thank you.

One more question. The voltage at the base is changing between the half-cycles?

@TRAXX What exactly do you mean?

Does the voltage at the base changes between the signal amplitudes?

@TRAXX I would call it "base potential" in reference to ground or the negative side of the B1 battery in this case. A voltage always involves two points and is a difference in potential between two points. If you say "the battery voltage" you would be correct because the voltage is across the battery or between the two output terminals of the battery. You could even say "base-emitter voltage" because you're specifying two points and the voltage across/between them. But when you specify only one point, the more appropriate term is "potential" (although many people use it interchangeably).

@TRAXX However, in this circuit we know we mean the voltage between the base and the ground when we say "base voltage" because it is marked in the schematic that way. And to FINALLY answer your question, YES, the base voltage changes with the input signal, and the emitter voltage tracks it (minus the 0.6V Vbe forward bias voltage drop).

Building an amplifier
While it is great to break down a finished electronic circuit and explain all its parts, a circuit as famous as this one deserves a deeper dive. We should build it up step by step, explaining the purpose of each new component as we go along. A powerful way to achieve this is through a series of simulations that can bring static schematics to life. I will show here how this can be done with the help of CircuitLab and our imagination. You might wonder about some of the early steps in this build, but trust me, they will make sense later on.
Some of the quantity values differ from those in your schematic, but this is not significant for this conceptual circuit. The important thing is to understand the idea and logic behind it.
Transistor current source
Transistors are controlled by input voltage but regulate the output current through the load. In this sense, they are voltage-to-current converters or simply current sources. For example, in the circuit below, I have applied 565 mV constant voltage to the input (base-emitter junction) of the transistor. As a result, 1 mA output current flows through the ammeter connected at the output. It is almost independent of either the ammeter's resistance or the supply voltage; hence the name "constant current source".

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note that setting Iout by adjusting Vbe I have made Iout input variable and Vbe output. I frequently use this empirical technique as follows: First, I double-click the source symbol to open its Parameters window. Then, I begin adjusting the source voltage while monitoring the ammeter. When it reads the desired value (1 mA here), I stop the adjustment. By the way, this is another example of negative feedback, where the output current is used to control the input voltage, ensuring stability.
Note also that in this simple transistor current source (sink) we rely solely on the transistor's ability to vary its "resistance" in order to maintain a relatively constant current. It does this without any regard for whether it has achieved its goal (i.e., there is no negative feedback).
Current source with emitter resistor
This current source becomes much better if we introduce negative feedback using resistor Re in the emitter. This results in an emitter follower that maintains a constant voltage across a constant resistance; as a result the current is constant.

simulate this circuit

... why does the emitter resistor in figure 1.2.1 stabilize the current source?

In contrast to the simple transistor current source above, here we have forced the transistor to monitor the current (through the voltage drop across the resistor Re) and make corrections as needed. This achieves greater accuracy in maintaining the current. Let's consider an example.
Imagine that in the circuit above, we switch the ammeter range and its resistance, accordingly the total resistance, increases to 1 кΩ. In the first moment, the transistor fails to react and the current decreases, correspondingly decreasing the voltage across the emitter resistor. Since the base voltage remains constant, the voltage Vbe at the transistor's input increases, and it begins to increase its collector current until (almost) restores its magnitude.

simulate this circuit
In its most perfect form, we can see this principle in current sources made with an operational amplifier.
Voltage amplifier with floating load
But we want a voltage out, not a current. So, we add a (6 kΩ) resistor Rc to turn that (1 mA) current back into a (6 V) voltage (half of Vcc).

simulate this circuit
However, a new problem arises - Vout is not referenced to ground but to Vcc (because Rc is not connected to ground but to Vcc).
Voltage amplifier with grounded load
So, we decide to take not the voltage VRc across the resistor as the output, but its complement to the supply voltage (Vout = Vcc - VRc). That is why the circuit turns out to be inverting.

simulate this circuit
Ultimately, we have created a DC amplifier with a quiescent (bias) input voltage of 2 V and a quiescent output voltage of 6 V. Or as they say, the circuit is "properly biased", and we only need to apply an input voltage.
The problem is that we would like to apply (add) it in parallel (because the input source is grounded) but we cannot do this because it is an ideal voltage source that rigidly sets 2 V at the transistor input.
Poor input voltage source
The remedy is a bit strange - we intentionally "degrade" the perfect input source by adding a resistor Rb in series (your schematics).

simulate this circuit
Divider voltage source
We can do this simply using two resistors (Rb1 and Rb2) connected in a voltage divider.

simulate this circuit
Shifting voltage sources
Circuit configuration
Now we can apply an input voltage at the midpoint between the two resistors (i.e., in parallel with the output of the "poor" source). However, this voltage varies around zero, while it should vary around the midpoint. So we need, figuratively speaking, to "shift" it up by 2 V. Thus, it will actually be added to the bias voltage.
At the output, on the other hand, we need to shift it down from the 6 V quiescent voltage to zero (because we want the voltage across the load to vary around zero).
We can do these voltage shifts simply by connecting "shifting" voltage sources in series. I have represented them as batteries (2V B1 and 6V B2) because they are "floating" (not firmly connected to ground).
Circuit operation
Vin = 0 V: In fact, there is no difference in the values of the quantities between this and the previous Schematic 1.6. The circuit is in a steady state. The zero input voltage is raised by 2 V and is applied to the base of the transistor. The 6 V collector voltage is lowered by 6 V and becomes zero output voltage.

simulate this circuit
No current flows in the input circuit because the 2 V input bias voltage is compensated by the equivalent 2 V "shifting up" voltage source. Ditto the same in the output circuit where the 6 V quiescent voltage is compensated by the equivalent 6 V "shifting down" voltage source (another reason is that an "ideal" voltmeter is connected as a load).
Vin = 100 mV: Now let's increase the zero input voltage by 100 mV (1 V is too much for this amplifier). This change is transferred from B1 and appears at the base of the transistor. It starts to conduct more and its collector voltage decreases by 410 mV. Now this change is transferred from B2 and the output voltage goes by 410 mV below zero.

simulate this circuit
In the input circuit Vin + VB1 > Vb, so input current (provided by B1) enters the input of the circuit and tries to discharge B1. In the output circuit Vc < VB2, so output current (provided by B2) enters the circuit output and tries to discharge B2.
Vin = -100 mV: Then let's decrease the zero input voltage by 100 mV so it goes 100 mV underground. The change is transferred from B1 and appears at the base of the transistor. It starts to conduct less and its collector voltage increases by 410 mV. This change is transferred from B2 and the output voltage goes by 410 mV above zero.

simulate this circuit
So, if we DC sweep (change linearly) the input voltage from -100 mV to 100 mV, the output voltage changes from 410 mV to -410 mV (the gain is about -4).

Shifting capacitors
Floating voltage sources are difficult to implement. So, a long time ago, people came up with the idea of using charged capacitors for this purpose.
Initial charging
After powering on, the capacitors begin to charge. Аfter some time, they almost perfectly replicate the quiescent voltages.

simulate this circuit
Note that C1 charges through the input source (represented by a short circuit in the schematic), and C2 charges through the load. This means that they should have a low internal resistance.

High-resistance load
So, if the load has a very high resistance (1 MΩ in the schematic below) or there is no load at all (as in your schematic), C2 will take a very long time to charge or may not be able to charge at all!

simulate this circuit
Let's see it in the simulation.

AC input voltage
Now it is time to apply a (100 mV) AC input voltage. It is transmitted from C1 to the base of the transistor, appears amplified at the collector, and finally is transmitted from C2 to the load.

simulate this circuit
Let's observe the voltages at the four interesting points in the circuit - Vin, Vb, Vc and VRL.

I assume you have noticed that the gain is too low. The reason is the emitter resistor Re, which introduces negative feedback. This is beneficial because it stabilizes the operating point but at the same time reduces the gain.
Bypass emitter capacitor
So let's apply another "capacitor trick" - to shunt Re with a capacitor Ce. This will keep the emitter voltage relatively constant. There is no AC negative feedback; there is only DC one.

simulate this circuit
The result is obvious - the gain increases dramatically.


Thank you for this nice breakdown analysis. Why Re in fig. 1.2 ensures more stable current than in fig. 1.1?

And why is IOut 1mA?

@TRAXX, In Fig. 1.1, we rely solely on the transistor's ability to vary its "resistance" in order to maintain a relatively constant current. It does this without any regard for whether it has achieved its goal (i.e., there is no negative feedback). In Fig. 1.2, we have forced the transistor to monitor the current (through the voltage drop across the resistor) and make corrections as needed. This achieves greater accuracy in maintaining the current. In its most perfect form, we can see this principle in current sources made with an operational amplifier.

@TRAXX, I have set Iout = 1 mA by adjusting Vbe = 564.8 mV. I frequently use this empirical technique as follows: First, I double-click the source symbol to open its Parameters window. Then, I begin adjusting the source voltage while monitoring the ammeter. When it reads 1 mA, I stop the adjustment. By the way, this is another example of negative feedback, where the output current is used to control the input voltage, ensuring stability.

@TRAXX, While my answer is long, there are still many details to clarify as this is a large topic. I would be happy to do so if you have any further questions about anything in my answer that is unclear to you. I will reflect our comments in my answer.

Your username suits you well. You seem to be more of a geek than I am. While your explanation is great and builds the whole circuit from the ground up, it is a little too much for most people, unless they want to learn the whole basic theory behind it. I took the simpler route, assuming some basic knowledge and not going too far into theory. Your view of the Ic as an input with the Vbe as an output is unusual, to say the least. Since the Ic is fairly independent from collector voltage (within a range), and is dependent on the base-emitter current, you're stretching quite a bit.

But I understand how the Ic, which is almost the same as Ie, can affect the Vbe and thus Ib when there is a current-dependent voltage drop (such as across an emitter resistor) between emitter and ground, and thus a negative feedback between Ic and Vbe or Ib.

@Edin Fifić, thank you! It is so nice when there is an adequate response to what we have written. You are right about the username; I am indeed obsessed with circuit ideas and have been for a long time, since my school years. Perhaps it is a reaction to the dogmatic teaching methods and sterile explanations in textbooks. As you noted, this step-by-step approach is the best way to explain circuits because it shows the evolution of ideas. However, such an explanation cannot be brief because it is built on a circuit (simulation) broken down into many sub-circuits…

… and each of them is accompanied by explanations. Of course, some of the steps could be removed as they are not directly related to the OP's question. But I intuitively felt that they needed them and that is why I left them in. Perhaps it is best to let them say if that is the case.
My remark about the swapped roles of Ic and Vbe could also have been omitted, but it is so fundamental to negative feedback circuits (and life in general) that I could not bring myself to do it…

… I mean, if we change the input of a device so that its output is equal to a certain value, then the output becomes the input and the input becomes the output. In your example with the emitter resistor, this means the following:

… Normally, a (input) current flows through the emitter resistor and creates an (output) voltage. But here we keep this voltage equal to an external input voltage and then the current becomes the output (Fig. 1.2). I have discussed this phenomenon in correspondence with Gordon Deboo.

@Circuitfantasist No, way, are you telling I am talking to a university professor? If that is the case, I am honored. You are also not too far from me, about 8 and half hours drive. Speaking of circuit ideas, I had posted one here about the simplest discrete 555 IC "equivalent" I could come up with in a couple of days, using only 6 ordinary BJTs, but some, I would say envious, guys closed it. I then posted it on EEVblog, link here: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/my-own-simplest-discrete-555-timer-design/  (no output driver, my main idea was the simplest design to understand 555).

@Circuitfantasist I apologize, I haven't looked at your info before. Again, I am honored. If you are ever coming to Bosnia, please let me know, I will be glad to meet you in person, even help if I can. Re: my 555 circuit, it came out of a desperation to solve an issue in my circuit. Up to that point, I never fully analyzed and understood the 555 IC, and was forced to do so at that point. For easier tracing, I decided to "re-imagine" its basic building blocks in the simplest way possible. Another goal was to share it as a teaching tool in schools, as only basic BJT understanding is needed.

@Edin Fifić, Thank you for the warm response! This is how it should be everywhere, not just in the Balkan Peninsula :-) You have a unique ability to explain things simply. I am truly enjoying exploring your discrete equivalent of the 555 timer; there is nothing superfluous about it. I especially like the transistor SR flip-flop and its resistive control. Years ago, I quickly soldered two transistor stages on a breadboard and made a movie for my students.

My favorite part was directly applying a "+" to the transistor collectors and asking the students why transistors did not burn out :-)
Envy really causes problems here. I have thought a lot about this phenomenon and even discussed it with Gemini AI.
Thank you for your responsiveness again. If I ever pass through Bosnia, I will call, even though at this age I try to avoid traveling.

@Circuitfantasist I've looked at your video, it's a simple SR latch. It's easy to see why transistor doesn't burn out: first of all, by shorting its collector to ground you are actually bypassing the transistor, so you're taking away the current from it, not adding to it. Additionally, there is a collector resistor which limits the current. I see you have added resistors across LEDs, probably because of the LED voltage drop affecting the circuit function. Same problem happens when you place red on one, and green on the other side; the SR latch will default to the green being on...

@Circuitfantasist ..because the lower Vf drop on red will turn the other transistor on. Sometimes it even prevents SR latch from functioning properly, as one frustrated poster discovered and posted a question. It also made me realize that I should have used a plain diode on one side of my SR latch instead of the double resistance value for the base of one transistor to make the other side default ON. I will add that modification later on, and I might add an output buffer and see how much does it improve the speed of my circuit.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Circuitfantasist Hi teacher, why does the emitter resistor in figure 1.2 stabilize the current source?

@TRAXX, see my edit (Schematic 1.2.2 and explanations added). Re ("emitter degeneration") is a big topic and deserves special attention. I suppose this question has been asked many times here, but if you want, we can give it a new interpretation.
